# JavaScript Regex has different results after it is executed

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that determines (I hope) if a string is a URL or not.

```
/^(((\/[\w-]+)+\/?)|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)[\w-]+))((\.[\w-]+)?([\w.,@?^=%&amplL\/~+#-]*[\w@?~=%&amp;:\/~+#-])?)$/gi
```

What I find is that if I save that regex to an object, then test the same string twice, I get two different results as shown in this JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gpc5trsw/

The code in this fiddle looks like this:

```
var test = /^(((\/[\w-]+)+\/?)|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)[\w-]+))((\.[\w-]+)?([\w.,@?^=%&amplL\/~+#-]*[\w@?~=%&amp;:\/~+#-])?)$/gi
var str = "/api/WebTest";

document.getElementById("firstCtr").innerHTML = /^(((\/[\w-]+)+\/?)|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)[\w-]+))((\.[\w-]+)?([\w.,@?^=%&amplL\/~+#-]*[\w@?~=%&amp;:\/~+#-])?)$/gi.test(str)
document.getElementById("secondCtr").innerHTML = /^(((\/[\w-]+)+\/?)|(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)[\w-]+))((\.[\w-]+)?([\w.,@?^=%&amplL\/~+#-]*[\w@?~=%&amp;:\/~+#-])?)$/gi.test(str)


document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = test.test(str)
document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = test.test(str)
```

With the following HTML:

```
<div>
First Run Control: <span id="firstCtr"></span>
</div>
<div>
Second Run Control: <span id="secondCtr"></span>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
First Run: <span id="first"></span>
</div>
<div>
Second Run: <span id="second"></span>
```

The resulting HTML output is as such:

> First Run Control: **true**
>   Second Run Control: **true**
>
> ---
>
> First Run: **true**
>   Second Run: **false**

Why does the results of the test change the second time it's tested on the object version?  JavaScript can be a cruel mistress sometimes...

Comment: [Remove `g` flag](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/gpc5trsw/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the /g, the regex object will remember ur last position every call u make. It will work and get the correct result the first time, but in the next call it will start from the point after the first match.

it will be clear if u have 2 matches inside as below example

```
var test = /\d+/gi
var str = "1234 vvv 3333";
document.getElementById("firstCtr").innerHTML = /\d+/gi.test(str);
document.getElementById("secondCtr").innerHTML = /\d+/gi.test(str);
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = test.test(str);
document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = test.test(str);
```

The output result will be

```
First Run Control: true 
Second Run Control: true 
First Run: true
Second Run: true
```

if you change the str to "1234 vvvv"

you will get the same as your previous results

```
 First Run: true 
 Second Run: false
```